# Unable to apply Custom Adapter notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, adapter, listadapter, notifydatasetchanged

Sorry, If you find this question repetitive. But I have looked at all other solution an I am unable to find any solution to my problem of applying notifyDataSetChanged().

My current code: From VenueSQL1 Activity I am calling custom Adapter

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try{
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog

        if(count==1){
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
            count++;
        }


        state = lv.onSaveInstanceState();
        final ListAdapter myadapter=new customAdapterVenues(VenueSQL1.this,contactList1);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
                }
            });
            lv.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }
```

customAdapterVenues

/**
 * Created by Shubham on 6/21/2015.
 */

```
public class customAdapterVenues extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{

private Context mcontext;
public String unique_id1,Cost1,Type1,Name1;
public ArrayList<Integer> flags=new ArrayList<>();
static final ArrayList<Integer> set=new ArrayList<>();
String android_id,android_id1;
String unique_id,Name,Type="weddinghalls",Cost;
int flag=0;
int pos=0;





public customAdapterVenues(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> main) {

    super(context, R.layout.list_item, main);
   // this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mcontext=context;


}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater shubhamsinflator=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customview=shubhamsinflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
     android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    //this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    try {
        flag=0;
       flags.add(position,0);
      //  set.add(position,0);


        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);

        final String name1 = map.get("Name");
        Name=name1;
        Log.d("flag:",String.valueOf(position));

        String address1 = map.get("Area");
        String image = map.get("Image");
        String cost = map.get("Cost");
       // if(set.get(position)==0) {
            unique_id = map.get("UniqueId");
          //  set.set(position, 1);
        //}
        android_id1=map.get("UserId");
        Cost=cost;
        final String phone = map.get("Telephone");
        //phone=phone.replace(" ","");
        // String name1 = map.get("name");
        //String name1=getItem(position).
        TextView shubhamsText = (TextView) customview.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView shubhamsText2 = (TextView) customview.findViewById(R.id.address);
        TextView shubhamsText3 = (TextView) customview.findViewById(R.id.price);
        TextView shubhamsText4 = (TextView) customview.findViewById(R.id.price1);
        ImageView shubhamsimage = (ImageView) customview.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        com.example.shubham.myapp.CircleImageView call = (com.example.shubham.myapp.CircleImageView) customview.findViewById(R.id.but);
        call.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        //callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                        //getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
                        myDialog(name1, phone);


                    }


                }
        );   


        shubhamsText.setText(name1);
        shubhamsText2.setText(address1);
        //cost = cost.replace("Per Plate", "");
        shubhamsText3.setText("Rs. "+cost);
        shubhamsText4.setText("Per Plate");
        if (cost.equals("0")) {
            shubhamsText3.setText("Price on");
            shubhamsText4.setText("Request");
            //  shubhamsText3.setText(" ");

        if (!image.equals("NA"))
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(image).into((ImageView) customview.findViewById(R.id.imageView2));
        else
            shubhamsimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ina);

        //shubhamsimage.setImageResource(p);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Hello","hello");

    }
        return customview;

    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=1000*15;
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS="http://shubhamsapp.esy.es/";

private void myDialog(String name1, final String phone)
{
    dialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(name1+"\n"+" " +phone);

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int w) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
            getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Don't Call",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int w) {
            //Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            //callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
            //getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog=dialogBuilder.create();
    //dialog.setTitle("Hey");
    dialog.show();


}
```

}

This is working for me. But the problem is each time items are added to listview the adapter starts printing from the starting position producing a small lag in the application. What I want is to make it start displaying from the list items that have been added ecently and previous items remain as it is and are not affected by it.
Can I do it with notifyDataSetChanged and where to add it as I have tried everywhere but it does not work.
Also sometimes I get the error'the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed-but-listview-did-not-receive-a-notification'. For that I have added thread in the VenueSQL1 activity . Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for lagging your program you can use ViewHolder pattern inside getView method
and whenever you add new data to you arraylist jst use you adapter object with notifyDataSetChanged()
it will work

Comment: Thanks. You solved my problem that I had from starting .

Answer (score 0):

Just  add the new item to data structure in your case to hashmap,whenever new item is added.

And don't forget to call.
myadapter.notifysetdatachanged();
It will reflect the new data in your listview.

Comment: I am adding that to the list. But I myadapter.notifyDataSetCahanged() is not even definded by the compiler . It can be applied only in the customadaptervenues class using this.notifydatasetcanged(). But I am not able to understand where to apply it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was making a mistake as I had used ListAdapter myadapter=new customAdapterVenues(VenueSQL1.this,contactList1); In place of ListAdapter I had to use customAdapterVenues which is why notifydatasetchanged was not available.